# how to push a task to background in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, background-process

I am working on a project where i require to send messages to clients. I'd like to push this $http call to the background and only receive a small message at the top saying that messages were sent. Like in google mail box . Right now i have to wait for the messages to sent till then my modal freezes( I am using modal to enter the details in a form ). Thank you in advance for your help.

```
var data = {
                "object":"value"
            };

            Data.post('url', data).then(function (result) {
                if (result.status != 'error') {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                    alert('sent message')

                } else {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            })
```

this is the process i need to send to the background. so what i want is that the modal needs to close as soon as i hit send report button which calls the above code. i want the above code to run in background and just get a small alert message at the top saying if the message was sent or not

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducable sample to attract more answers

Comment: @SavadKP please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close the modal at once, make the `close()` call before you make the request.

```
var data = {
            "object":"value"
        };

        $modalInstance.close();
        Data.post('url', data).then(function (result) {
            if (result.status != 'error') {
                alert('sent message')

            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
```

Comment: i accept this as the answer since it achieved what i wanted. thanx a ton

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by Using Web Workers with AngularJS,Here is an example of a webworker in a service

```
     var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.factory("HelloWorldService",['$q',function($q){

        var worker = new Worker('doWork.js');
        var defer = $q.defer();
        worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
          defer.resolve(e.data);
        }, false);

        return {
            doWork : function(myData){
                defer = $q.defer();
                worker.postMessage(myData); // Send data to our worker. 
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };

});
```

[here also](http://www.codingterminal.com/articles/092014/1/XMLHttpRequest%20using%20AngularJS%20Promises%20and%20HTML5%20Web%20Workers.php) working example of web workers in Angular

Comment: i saw an example of this web worker code. but doesnt it freeze the ui till the process is run completely?

Comment: thank you . i ll use this in my future for background processes but right now @tetaxa 's answer helped me achieve what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use  angular plugin https://github.com/vkiryukhin/ng-vkthread

which allows you to execute a function in a separate thread.

basic usage:

```
/* function to execute in a thread */
function foo(n, m){ 
    return n + m;
}

/* create an object, which you pass to vkThread as an argument*/
var param = {
      fn: foo      // <-- function to execute
      args: [1, 2] // <-- arguments for this function
    };

/* run thread */
vkThread.exec(param).then(
   function (data) {
       console.log(data);  // <-- thread returns 3 
    }
);
```

See http://www.eslinstructor.net/ng-vkthread/demo/  for examples and documentation

--Vadim